# Guess a Number Game

Tags: python, performance, beginner

I am trying to create a simple Python project. It's a minigame about guessing a number.

It's a game where the computer will pick a random number from 1 to 10.

- The player needs to guess it correctly.
- Every wrong attempt will give you a clue.
- 3 clues and the player will lose.

I've built the code and it works just fine. Here's the code :

```py
total = 0
guessme = 0

def GuessNum(guess):
    global total
    global guessme
    
    prime = [2, 3, 5, 7]

    if total == 0:
        randnum = random.randint(1,10)
        guessme = randnum

    total += 1

    if guess == guessme:
        print("You are correct!")
        guessme = 0
        total = 0
    else:
        if total == 1:
        if guessme % 2 == 0:
            print("The number is even")
        else:
            print("The number is odd")
            
        elif total == 2:
        if guessme > 5:
            print("The number is greater than 5")
        else:
            print("The number is smaller than 5")
        
        elif total == 3:
        if guessme in prime:
            print("The number is prime")
        else:
            print("The number is not a prime")
            
        else:
        guessme = 0
        total = 0
        print("You failed to guess the number.")
```

Are there ways to make this code much more efficient or shorter? I am still new at programming so I would love to learn new things.

Comment: How are you taking input from the user? Also since you are using a function try to use return instead of global variables.

Comment: Printing `The number is smaller than 5` when the number is 5 is, hm, tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The code is fairly okay and readable. Since you highlighted `performance`, my review would not touch on some areas that are lacking.

### Prefer `random.random()` to generate pseudorandom numbers

```
import timeit

test1 = '''
import random
random.randint(1,10)
'''

test2= '''
import random
int(10 * random.random())
'''

tt1 = timeit.repeat(stmt=test1, repeat=5, number=1)
print('randint time taken: ', min(tt1))

tt2 = timeit.repeat(stmt=test2, repeat=5, number=1)
print('random.random() time taken: ', min(tt2))
```

On running the above program, the following results were gotten. NOTE: The results might vary on your computer, but there is still some difference.

```
randint time taken = 2.1700000005546375e-06

random.random() time taken = 6.056000074750045e-06
```

Though the difference is insignificant, it might mean a lot when the range increases.